# How to make background video (or any element) ignore scrolling in React JS?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

As the title says, im trying to make my background video ignore any kind of scrolling.

```
<video autoPlay loop muted
        style={{
            position:"absolute",
            width:"100%",
            left: "50%",
            top: "50%",
            height: "100%",
            objectFit:"cover",
            transform:"translate(-50%, -50%)",
            zIndex:"-1",
            overflow:"hidden",
        }}
        >
            <source src={Backvid} type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
```

It's within a div with the rest of the elements, so I'm trying to make it stationary while I'm scrolling the elements in front of it.
[Example of the video being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atPrE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the video element is a direct child of the body?

Try `position: fixed`

`position: absolute` is still relative to the parent. So when you scroll, the body moves thus will your video.